# How to show NSWindow only once in a document based cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa

```
- (void)showPromotionWindow
{
    [_promotionWindow showWindow:self];
    [_promotionWindow.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

My project is document based application, so when call  `showPromotionWindow`, each document window will launch a window, but i want only launch the window once for multiple document. How to implement this?

**Edit**

I found one method is to custom this window such as `PromotionWindow`, and then check if all the windows contains a `PromotionWindow`:

```
for(id window in [[NSApplication sharedApplication]windows])
{
    if([[window className]isEqualToString:@"PromotionToolsWindow"])
    {
    }
}
```

**Edit2**

Another method is to use `static`

```
static PromotionWindow *promotionWindow;
```

Do you have any other better methods?

Comment: Do you have one window per app or do you want to open the promotion window of the front document only?

Comment: @Willeke, the document-based app have one promotion window per document, but i want all the documents to share one promotion window

Comment: @Willeke, should i use `static` member to do this?

Comment: `showPromotionWindow` should be a action, and `promotionWindow` a property of the app delegate.